# javascript in MVC - populate a list from another list

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

In an Umbraco MVC partial view I have declared a parameter of type List, based on a custom model.

```
List<MyModel> modelList = new List<MyModel>();

public class MyModel{
        public int ArticleID { get; set; }
        public string ArticleName { get; set; }
        public string ArticleType { get; set; }
        public bool isSelected { get; set; }
    }
```

That list get populated with data from another model before being rendered in a row.
On a button click even I want to take that list and loop through it, any rows which have been selected have to be added to another list, the problem is I can't seem to access it in a function on the same view.

Here's what I have at the moment, I'm fine with populating the other list so I just put an alert in and put a breakpoint on it to see what is in modelList, but I get the error "AddToList is not defined" and I think it's to do with how I'm trying to access the list.

Can anyone tell me how I should be doing this please?

```
function AddToList() {
     $.each(@modelList, function () {
        alert("function hit");
    });
}
```

Comment: You have to store @modelList to a javascript variable first. What exactly are the properties of your model? As you have to manually assign them.

Comment: Hi, I've updated the post to show the model 
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to convert your `server side model` into `javascript array`, after that you can perform `each` operation on it.

```
function AddToList()
 {
      var data = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
      $.each(data, function () {
        alert("function hit");
     });
}
```